# How to create a new column of datatype map<string,string> in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column(not from an existing columns) having `MapType(StringType(),StringType())` how do I achieve this.

So far, I was able to write the below code but it's not working.

```
df = df.withColumn("normalizedvariation",lit(None).cast(MapType(StringType(),StringType())))
```

Also I would like to know the different methods to achieve the same, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you can try, newMapColumn here woukld be the name of the Map column.
You can see the output I got below. If that is not what you are looking for, please let me know. Thanks!

Also you will have to import the functions using the below line:
*from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit,create_map*

[image]